# Update two columns in a DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to update two columns of DataTable in a single line using LINQ query. Currently I am using following two lines to do the same:

```
oldSP.Select(string.Format("[itemGuid] = '{0}'", itemGuid)).ToList<DataRow>().ForEach(r => r["startdate"] = stDate);
oldSP.Select(string.Format("[itemGuid] = '{0}'", itemGuid)).ToList<DataRow>().ForEach(r => r["enddate"] = enDate);
```

How can I do this in one line, using one `Select`?

Comment: The "single line" approach sometimes is less readable and inefficient as in this case. Use a linq query and a foreach loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have a huge datatable(1000 records) which with multiple line approach will take more time than single line.

Comment: You are confusing lines in code with cpu cycles. One line in code can take 1000  times as much time as 100 lines of code. Always use the most readable and maintainable approach first.

Comment: @TimSchmelter here in each line we are going to do select, isn't 1000 selects are better than 2000 selects?

Comment: You could simply store the result since you are selecting the same DataRows twice. But the `ToList` is redundant since `DataTable.Select` already returns a collection, hence your doubling the required memory for nothing. The `LINQ` approch you've accepted does not need another collection (than the `DataTable`) at all. The `foreach` enumerates the query directly. You could also enumerate `DataTable.Rows` in a `foreach` and use `if(condition...)` to check if this row must be updated. That would be the most efficient and direct approach.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do it in one 'line', just pass appropriate action delegate to ForEach method:

```
oldSP.Select(string.Format("[itemGuid] = '{0}'", itemGuid))
     .ToList<DataRow>()
     .ForEach(r => { 
        r["startdate"] = stDate;
        r["enddate"] = enDate;
      });
```

Also you can use LINQ to DataSet (looks more readable to me, than one-liner):

```
var rowsToUpdate = 
    oldSP.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("itemGuid") == itemGuid);

foreach(var row in rowsToUpdate)
{
    row.SetField("startdate", stDate);
    row.SetField("enddate", enDate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use curly bracers to do two on more operations:

```
oldSP.Select(string.Format("[itemGuid] = '{0}'", itemGuid))
       .ToList<DataRow>()
       .ForEach(r => { r["enddate"] = enDate); r["startdate"] = stDate; });
```

But for code readability I would use old-fashioned `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
oldSP.Select(string.Format("[itemGuid] = '{0}'", itemGuid)).ToList<DataRow>()
     .ForEach(r => { r["startdate"] = stDate; r["enddate"] = enDate; });
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't like any of the examples I saw on the web, so here's my example

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Year");
        dt.Columns.Add("Month");
        dt.Columns.Add("Views");
        for (int year = 2011; year < 2015; year++)
        {
            for (int month = 1; month < 13; month++)
            {
                DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
                newRow[0] = year;
                newRow[1] = month;
                newRow[2] = 0;
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        //if using Lambda 
        //var test = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Year") == "2013" && x.Field<string>("Month") == "2").ToList();

        var test = (from x in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where x.Field<string>("Year") == "2013"
                    where x.Field<string>("Month") == "2"
                    select x).ToList();


        test[0][0] = "2015";

        dt.AcceptChanges();
```

//if writing to sql use  dt.SubmitChanges() instead

Comment: The question clearly states "Update two columns in a DataTable using LINQ" and your solution is not based on linq.