# Update value in datatable from another datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Is there any way to update value in one datatable from another datatable.

For example lets say I have two datatables dt1 and dt2.

[image] [image]

As shown above, I have two datatable and I have to replace table_name column value in 1st datatable with the newtable_name column value from 2nd datatable with the mapping of table_name which is common in both the datatable.

Comment: take a look about "triggers" and it's funcionality, they may help you. You can also check about "jobs", but probably best approach for you is to use a trigger in second table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Veellicus. But this is c# .net  datatable which I got after some operation performed in the code.

Comment: Do you want to do this in the database table, or in an in-memory datatable? (These are two different things and you need to use different approaches depending on which you're trying to update)

Comment: No Tim. I don't want to do this in database table. I just only want this in c# datatable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for the Sample Data below:

```
foreach(DataRow row in originalTable.Rows)
{
  DataRow rowsToUpdate = newNameTable.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("table_name") == row.Field<string>("table_name"));
  row.SetField("table_name",  rowsToUpdate.Field<string>("table_name_new"));      
}
```

My Sample Data I used to check whether this works or not:

```
DataTable originalTable = new DataTable(); 
originalTable.Clear();

originalTable.Columns.Add("Id");
originalTable.Columns.Add("table_name");

DataRow originalRow1 = originalTable.NewRow();
originalRow1["Id"] = 1;
originalRow1["table_name"] = "Table1";
originalTable.Rows.Add(originalRow1);

DataRow originalRow2 = originalTable.NewRow();
originalRow2["Id"] = 2;
originalRow2["table_name"] = "Table2";
originalTable.Rows.Add(originalRow2);

DataTable newNameTable = new DataTable(); 
newNameTable.Clear();

newNameTable.Columns.Add("table_name");
newNameTable.Columns.Add("table_name_new");

DataRow newNameRow = newNameTable.NewRow();
newNameRow["table_name"] = "Table1";
newNameRow["table_name_new"] = "Table1_new";
newNameTable.Rows.Add(newNameRow);

DataRow newNameRow2 = newNameTable.NewRow();
newNameRow2["table_name"] = "Table2";
newNameRow2["table_name_new"] = "Table2_new";
newNameTable.Rows.Add(newNameRow2);
```

Comment: Thanks Markus. This is working fine. But how about performance in large amount of data? Because I have large amount of data in both the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for code as below in c#:

```
dt1.Merge(dt2);
dt1.AcceptChanges();
```

Here **dt1** records are updated with the values in DataTable **dt2** in the 1st statement. And the second statement commits the updations made to the DataTable **dt1**. But the key thing that you need to ensure is that both the tables should have same schema i.e., **Column names** in this case

Comment: Merge functionality will not solve my purpose because it does not replace your value with new one in existing value.

Answer (score 0):

I think Linq is the way to go if you're on a current rev of the framework.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855772/update-two-columns-in-a-datatable-using-linq) should get you started.

Comment: I am not sure this will work for me or not as i am not too much familiar with the LInq and Generic list.

Comment: OK, look up a DataRelation object. You can join the two tables in memory, and once you do that you should be able to update Table_name in t1 with the newTable_name value in T2. It'll take a little work, but it's doable.

Comment: DataRelation needs uniqueID column for relation between two datatables for mapping and I just have table_name for mapping which is not unique.

Comment: Then you'll have no choice - loop through dt2, get the old and new names, and update the name in t1 with the new value. This would probably be easier to do in the database with a two-line SQL statement, but that's not always an option...

Comment: Yeah Tim this is easier way to do using loop, but I am avoiding this because I have large number(millions) of data and it may slow down the performance of the application. That is the only reason that I am waiting for any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Loop it

```
DataTable First_Table = new DataTable();
DataTable Second_Table = new DataTable();



 for(int i =0 ; i<Frist_Table.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
         Second_Table.Rows[i]["Column_name"] =First_Table.Rows[i];["Column_name"]
   }
Second_Table.AcceptChanges();
```